# NuxtJS/Vue updating page data after mounte

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a HTTP request that calls after mounted like so

```
mounted: function() {
    return axios.get('/api/user/profile/stats')
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            return {
                stats: res
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e)
        })
}
```

But once it is done, the page is not updated where

```
<h2 class="text-green" v-if="stats" data-plugin="counterup">{{stats.ident}}</h2>
```

How can I get the data to reload once the request is successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the component data, you will need to assign to this.stats so it will be available elsewhere. Returning inside the mounted doesn't provide you anything as the return value is not used anywhere.

If you use Vue devtools for your browser it is also easy to see while inspecting the component data, that the stats property is not actually changed.